# Problem to asign class to <ul> with wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus

I have some problems to asign a class to  tag with wp_nav_menu() instead of asign the class to the  tag it creates a  and asign the class to that one.

My register_nav_menu function:

```
    function register_primary_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('primary-menu', __('Primary Menu'));
}
add_action('init', 'register_primary_menu');
```

wp_nav_menu:

```
<?php
                        $defaults = array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'primary-menu',
                        'menu'            => '',
                        'container'       => 'flase',
                        'container_class' => '',
                        'container_id'    => '',
                        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
                        'menu_id'         => '',
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                        'before'          => '<li>',
                        'after'           => '</li>',
                        'link_before'     => '',
                        'link_after'      => '',
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                        'depth'           => 0,
                        'walker'          => ''
                    );

                    wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

                    ?>
```

What I want is this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

And what I get is this:

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-56"><a href="[URL]">Page 1</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-58"><a href="[URL]">Page 2</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-60"><a href="[URL]">Page 3</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="[URL]">Sample Page</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I noticed `'container'=> 'flase',` here `'flase'` instead of `false`, this must not be a cause, but check correcting it.

Comment: Fixed that mispelling  :) But my issue still remains :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make sure your menu does setup correctly in that location in Appearance / Menus, unless it wont display that class. After you set the theme location to Primary Menu, it should work fine. No idea why, guess its a bug in WordPress.

Also fix the typo: `'container' => false`

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the typo. I dont understand what you mean I should fix in Appearance / Menus. Can you explain a bit more what you mean? Where under "Menu" should I set location?

Comment: https://cloudup.com/chB3re_CbGw

Comment: Hi, that solve the issue :) But there must be a way around this? I mean.. You never have to go into Apperance / Menu and do this when you download a theme?

Comment: Actually, you do... Otherwise it will display all of your pages in your menu.

Comment: Yes, but how to I give the "standard menu" a style? So even when all pages are showing it will still have the correct classes?

Comment: The class is there, just on a parent element. So style it like .navbar-nav instead of ul.navbar-nav, so it will work either way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set 'container' => 'ul'.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem and i fix it. My theme_location i set primary in the functions.php file, but i don't set that location in the wp admin -> Appearance and in the Menu Settings set your location.

[image]